# Dataframe slicing on multiple conditions Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns:

```
df:

x       y      z
334     290    3350.0
334     291    3350.5
334     292    3360.1
335     292    3360.1
335     292    3360.1
335     290    3351.0
335     290    3352.5
335     291    3333.1
335     291    3333.1
.
.
```

I'd like to check and parse values of each row from `row = n` to `row = n+7` into a **new dataframe** based on a couple of conditions:

1. df[n] != df[n+1]
2. df[n] != df[n+3]
3. df[n] != df[n+5]
4. df['x'][n] < df['x'][n+2]
5. df['x'][n] > df['x'][n+3]

If all of these are satisfied I want to write a new dataframe:

```
df_new = pd.concat([df[n], df[n+1], df[n+2], df[n+3], 
df[n+4], df[n+5], df[n+6], df[n+7]])
```

So the algorithm + output would look like:

```
for df[n] = 0:
1) [334     290    3350.0] != [334     291    3350.5]  True
2) [334     290    3350.0] != [335     292    3360.1]  True
3) [334     290    3350.0] != [335     290    3351.0]  True
4) 335 < 334  False
5) 335 > 335  False
```

So in this case it would **skip** the first iteration until we've gone down the **entire length of the dataframe** and made matches.

`df_new(first iteration) = df_new.concat([....]) = empty row values`

Is there an easy way to do this with speed in `Pandas`?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but this looks quite complex and prone to errors. Isn't there another way to achieve what you are trying to do?

Comment: I think it looks a bit more complicated than it actual is. Really I'm just trying to compare X, Y, Z values (together as a single row of 3 columns) or just X values (as a single row of 1 column) and making conditions on them.

Is there anything helpful I can provide to help understand better?

Comment: I understand what you're doing, but imo try to take a step back and think about solving it differently. But maybe im wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A. Get the appropriate shifts:

```
    n1 = df.shift(-1)
    n2 = df.shift(-2)
    n3 = df.shift(-3)
    n5 = df.shift(-5)
```

B. Satisfy conditions 1, 2 and 3:

```
cond = (df != n1) & (df != n3) & (df != n5)
```

C. Satisfy conditions 4, 5:

```
 cond['holder'] = (df.x < n2.x) & (df.x < n3.x)
```

D. Get bool series (we want any row with all 'True'):

```
boolidx = cond.all(axis=1)
```

E. Use to get result:

```
df.loc[boolidx]
```

Comment: `cond.any(axis=1)` or `cond.all(axis=1)`?

Answer (score 0):

I changed slightly your sample data, to have one positive result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [ 334, 290, 3350.0 ],
    [ 334, 291, 3350.5 ],
    [ 334, 292, 3360.1 ],
    [ 335, 292, 3360.1 ],
    [ 335, 292, 3360.1 ],
    [ 333, 290, 3351.0 ],
    [ 335, 290, 3352.5 ],
    [ 335, 291, 3333.1 ],
    [ 335, 291, 3333.1 ]], columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Then, for efficiency reason, I defined the following function:

```
def roll_win(a, win):
    shape = (a.shape[0] - win + 1, win, a.shape[1])
    strides = (a.strides[0],) + a.strides
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

It generates a *3-D* table, where *2nd* and *3rd* dimension are "rolling
windows" from the source *Numpy* array *a*. The size of window is *win*,
sliding vertically.
This way, processing of consecutive windows requires a loop running along
the first axis of the generated table (see below).

Due to usage of *as_strided* function it runs significantly quicker than
any "ordinary" Python loop (compare execution time with other solutions).

I couldn't use *rolling windows* provided by *Pandas*, because they were
created to compute some statistics, not for calling any user function
on the whole content of the current window.

Then I call this function:

```
tbl = roll_win(df.values, 7)
```

Note that *Numpy* array must have a **single** element type, so this
type is "generalized" to *float* because one source column is of
*float* type.

Then we have preparation steps for a loop processing each rolling window:

```
res = []    # Result container
idx = 0     # Rolling window index
```

The rest of the program is the loop:

```
while idx < len(tbl):
    tt = tbl[idx]  # Get the current rolling window (2-D)
    r0 = tt[0]     # Row 0
    # Condition
    cond = not((r0 == tt[1]).all() and (r0 == tt[3]).all()\
        and (r0 == tt[5]).all()) and tt[0][0] < tt[2][0]\
        and tt[0][0] > tt[3][0]
    if cond:   # OK
        # print(idx)
        # print(tt)
        res.extend(tt)  # Add to result
        idx += 7        # Skip the current result
    else:      # Failed
        idx += 1        # Next loop for the next window
```

In the "positive" case, I decided to start the next loop from the row
**following** the current match (*idx += 7*), to avoid possible partially
overlapping sets of source rows.
If you don't want this feature, add 1 do *idx* in both cases.

For demonstration purpose, you can uncomment test printouts above.

The only remaining thing is to create the target DataFrame, from rows
collected in *res*:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=res, columns=['x', 'y', 'z'], dtype=int)
```

Note that *dtype=int* will be obeyed only for *x* and *y* columns,
because values in *z* column have fractional part.